# CSS text input box hover

Tags: html, css, hover

I have created a text input box in HTML. I have added CSS to change the box so when the user hovers their mouse over it, the shadow changes but when I tried it in a browser nothing changed when I hovered my mouse over the box.

```
.searchBar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 307px;
    right: 392.5px;
    width: 500px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #f3efee;
    height:40px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px #f3efee;
}

.searchbar:focus {
    box-shadow: 10px 10px red;
}
```

Comment: Please create a [MCVE]. Without seeing your HTML nobody is going to be able to help you.

Comment: Is it .searchBar or .searchbar? I think you need to just fix the classname

Answer (score 1):

This pseudo class should work when hovering over the `.searchBar` element:

```
.searchBar:hover {
    box-shadow: 10px 10px red;
}
```

Comment: Also he has to capitalise the B

Answer (score 1):

Note that `:focus` and `:hover` are different properties.

Answer (score 0):

Change `.searchbar:focus`  to `.searchBar:focus` your class name `.searchBar` has an uppercase B.

```css
.searchBar {
    width: 500px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #f3efee;
    height:40px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px #f3efee;
}

.searchBar:focus {
    box-shadow: 10px 10px red;
}
```

```html
<div style="background: yellow; padding: 30px">
<input type="text" class="searchBar" />
</div>
```